# Spring Boot use multiple DataSources in one Transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, connection-pooling, hikaricp

My Setup is the following:

I Have a Spring Boot 2.1.1 Application. For Connection Pooling Hikari
is used.

I would like to write one service which routes the READs to a READER database and the WRITES to a Master database in one transaction/method.

So i want the following to get to work:

```
@Transactional
public test(Test test){
    Optional<Res> result = myRepo.findByAttr(test.getTest()); //do that on reader database
    validateIfResultExists(result); 

    myRepo.save(test);//do this on master database
}
```

For that i wrote a custom DbContextHolder:

```
public class DbContextHolder {
private static final ThreadLocal<DbType> contextHolder = new ThreadLocal<DbType>();


public static void setDbType(DbType dbType) {
    if(dbType == null){
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    contextHolder.set(dbType);
}

public static DbType getDbType() {
    if(contextHolder.get() == null){
        DbContextHolder.setDbType(DbType.MASTER);
    }

    return (DbType) contextHolder.get();
}

public static void clearDbType() {
    contextHolder.remove();
}
}
```

I also have a custom RoutingDataSource:

```
public class RoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {
@Override
protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
    return DbContextHolder.getDbType();
}
   }
```

And a DataSource for configuring database with hikari:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

private static final String PRIMARY_DATASOURCE_PREFIX = "spring.primary.datasource";
private static final String REPLICA_DATASOURCE_PREFIX = "spring.replica.datasource";

@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Value("${spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout}")
private Long CONNECTION_TIMEOUT;

@Value("${spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout}")
private Long IDLE_TIMEOUT;

@Value("${spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime}")
private Long MAX_LIFETIME_TIMEOUT;

@Value("${spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle}")
private int MINIMUM_IDLE;

@Value("${spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize}")
private int MAX_POOL_SIZE;

@Resource

@Bean
@Primary
public DataSource dataSource() {
    final RoutingDataSource routingDataSource = new RoutingDataSource();

    final DataSource primaryDataSource = buildDataSource("PrimaryHikariPool", PRIMARY_DATASOURCE_PREFIX);
    final DataSource replicaDataSource = buildDataSource("ReplicaHikariPool", REPLICA_DATASOURCE_PREFIX);

    final Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<>();
    targetDataSources.put(DbType.MASTER, primaryDataSource);
    targetDataSources.put(DbType.REPLICA, replicaDataSource);

    routingDataSource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);
    routingDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(primaryDataSource);

    return routingDataSource;
}

private DataSource buildDataSource(String poolName, String dataSourcePrefix) {
    final HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
    hikariConfig.setConnectionTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
    hikariConfig.setIdleTimeout(IDLE_TIMEOUT);
    hikariConfig.setMaxLifetime(MAX_LIFETIME_TIMEOUT);
    hikariConfig.setMinimumIdle(MINIMUM_IDLE);
    hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(MAX_POOL_SIZE);

    hikariConfig.setPoolName(poolName);
    hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(environment.getProperty(String.format("%s.url", dataSourcePrefix)));
    hikariConfig.setUsername(environment.getProperty(String.format("%s.username", dataSourcePrefix)));
    hikariConfig.setPassword(environment.getProperty(String.format("%s.password", dataSourcePrefix)));
    hikariConfig.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty(String.format("%s.driver", dataSourcePrefix)));

    return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
}

}
```

But that doesn't seem to work. If i log the current DbType everythint looks gread, but it doesn't work since i get the following error:

> ERROR: cannot execute INSERT in a read-only transaction

Comment: Multiple datasources in the same transaction would mean a distributed transaction. You'd need to do the handling somewhere in middleware, rather than your application code.

Comment: @Kayaman du you have an example? or a more specific description?

Comment: Not sure about the middleware either actually. Which database are you using?

Comment: If all you want to do is to read from one database and then write to another database you don't need a transaction that covers both of those operations, it will not give you any benefits. You can use TransactionTemplate.execute to execute them in separate transactions. On the other hand if your code becomes more complex with several reads or writes you should do as Kayaman said and use XA transaction manager.

Comment: @vitalyros i will check that out!

Comment: @Kayaman postgreSQL

Comment: If you will go by the way of separating reading from one database and writing to another into two transactions, be sure to create and use two transaction managers, one for each datasource.

Comment: How do you tell your application to switch between read and write dbs ?

Answer (score 0):

For making the transaction distributed, you can add the aspect around your transaction `(@Around("@annotation(transactional)"))` and by checking the type of transaction, you can apply which replica has to be called.